# How can I add hyperlinks without underlining or changing text color?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, hyperlink, text-formatting, styles

Whenever I use Microsoft Word's "insert hyperlink" tool, it automatically switches my text to a hyperlink font style. (blue, underlined text)

[image: Hyperlinked vs non-hyperlinked]

While I usually find this helpful, sometimes I want to add a hyperlink without affecting my font style.

For example, I have a caption written below an image which I want to hyperlink *without* changing the caption's font style or color.

[image: Hyperlink example]

I have tried manually changing the font color after adding the hyperlink, but manual changes to font color are overridden [when a hyperlink has been opened](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/hyperlinks-purple-and-microsoft-word-2010/93cb5832-dafc-4634-89a3-82358acf9b6a).

[image: Opened hyperlink style overrides manual font change]

**How can I hyperlink text in Microsoft Word 2013 without changing the font style?**

Answer (score 0):

First, set a hyperlink. It will give underline and blue color. Now, select that text, click on 'U' from font panel and finally, just change text color to 'automatic' . Thats it.

Comment: Selecting "Automatic" changes my caption color to *black*, rather than using my caption's original *grey* font.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without changing the theme's default font style, which would modify the style for *all* links, which isn't what you want.

The only way to accomplish this as of Office 2013 and previous versions is to insert the link, then modify the style of the text manually.

However, you can speed this process up by [creating a new style](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/word2013/styles/2/) with your desired font settings, selecting the link text, and applying the style by left-clicking it. That would work for Office 2013 and 2010.

Comment: Manual changes to a hyperlink's color are [overridden by the HyperlinkFollow style](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/hyperlinks-purple-and-microsoft-word-2010/93cb5832-dafc-4634-89a3-82358acf9b6a) if the link is opened or clicked on.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro I couldn't replicate that behavior in Office 2010, but the behavior might have changed in 2013. I changed a link to the "Strong" style, and after CTRL+Left Click, the style remained unchanged.